# Vim - pattern to match only first character of literal string

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to write a pattern that would match only the first character (can be any character, whitespace as well) of a string interpreted literally.

So given this function, that uses "very no magic" to literally match a string given as argument and then highlight that string, how can I modify it, so it only highlights the first character?

```
function! MatchFirst(i)
  highlight Red ctermbg=red ctermfg=0 guibg=#ff0000 guifg=#000000
  call matchadd('Red', '\V' . escape(a:i, '\'))
endfunction
```

So for example calling `MatchFirst('{^(sed')` on the following text, would only highlight the `{` if `{` is followed by `*(sed`, but not in any other place. Currently it highlights the whole given string `{^(sed`.

> Lorem ipsum do{^(lor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, e{^(sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo con{^(sequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rep{^(rehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

**LATER EDIT**

To give a bit of context, the argument for the `MatchFirst` function is the text visually selected by the user, so it can literally be anything, it can be `foobar`, `foo\ze\bar`, `&#@!^><..?/\\\`, `国字字`, etc.

Comment: Consider posting questions about Vim on the [vi.se] Stack Exchange, you might get more attention to it there than on SO.

Comment: @filbranden I just realized that I actually posted a different question on Vi and Vim a at some point and actually got an answer from you :) I posted this one on SO out of habit I guess.

Comment: It's all good... I tend to mention Vi and Vim in case posters don't know about it... Most of us check SO as well (I have a bookmark for questions tagged with "vim") but it's much easier to keep track of only one place... Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to select only part of a match in a Vim pattern is to use `\ze` to mark the end of the match. See [`:help /\ze`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cze) for more details.

You can use `\ze` directly under "very nomagic" mode `\V`. You'll find this under [`:help /\V`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CV):

> Use of `\V` means that after it, only **a backslash** and terminating character (usually `/` or `?`) have special meaning: "very nomagic"

Since `\ze` already starts with a backslash, you don't need to modify it at all for it to work under `\V`.

In your example of `{^(sed`, you can use `\V{\ze^(sed` to match the first `{` but only when it's part of `{^(sed`.

Putting it all together in your function, you can use:

```
call matchadd('Red',
    \ '\V' .  escape(strcharpart(a:i, 0, 1), '\') .
    \ '\ze' . escape(strcharpart(a:i, 1), '\'))
```

**NOTE:** You might have a corner case where `a:i` is an empty string, you might want to do something different in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I see a case where this is not working though, for example if there are double backslashes involved. For ex: `lorem foo\\bar ipsum`, then `MatchFirst("foo\\bar")` will not match. To give you a bit of context, this is for a small plugin I am writing and the argument is the visually selected text so it can literally be anything.

Comment: @skamsie The problem is actually with your *call*, you're using a double quoted string, so `"foo\\bar"` has actually only *one* backslash (try with `:echo` to see it.) Calling `MatchFirst('foo\\bar')` works as expected.

Comment: Thank you it works now :). I did not know there is a difference between double quotes and single quotes, but I've 'googled it' and I understand now. I have accepted your answer, however I would appreciate if you could explain in your anwser why `\ze` still works in this case. I though that using 'very no magic' makes **everyhing** to be interpreted as a regular string.

Comment: Updated to explain why `\ze` is safe under `\V`.

Comment: See `:help expr-string` for double quoted strings, vs. `:help literal-string` for single quoted ones. Also: https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html

Comment: Updated to use `strcharpart()` so it properly works with multi-byte characters too.

Comment: by multi-byte characters you mean something like `国` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I tested it with that sequence and it seemed to work correctly for me.